# XHTML/CSS Padding on inline element with linebreak

Tags: xhtml, inline, css

I have an inline element with a line break in it. It has padding on all sides. However, the side padding on where the line break cuts the element is not there.

This is what i mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/4Gs2E/

There should be 20px padding on the right of **tag** and left of **with** but there isnt.
The only other way I can see this working is if i create a new element for every line but this content will be dynamically generated and will not be in a fixed width container so i dont see that working out. Is there any other way I can do this in css without any javascript?

I want the final result to look like this :
http://jsfiddle.net/GNsw3/

but without any extra elements

i also need this to work with display inline only as I want the background to wrap around the text as inline block doesnt do this

Is this possible?

edit, altered the examples to make what i want more visible:

current
http://jsfiddle.net/4Gs2E/2/

what i want it to look like
http://jsfiddle.net/GNsw3/1/

Comment: Your 'Final Result' looks the same to me (Chrome).

Comment: check my edit, should make it clearer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In some cases you can use `box-shadow` for a workaround.

Move the right and left `padding` of the element to its parent and add two `box-shadow`s.

The result: http://jsfiddle.net/FpLCt/1/

Browser support for `box-shadow`: http://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow

**Update:**

There is also a new css property for this issue called [`box-decoration-break`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#box-decoration-break). It is currently only supported by opera, but hopefully [more browsers will implement this](http://bricss.net/post/24672339016/box-decoration-break-finally-coming-to-more-browsers) soon.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution for you, but it ain't pretty :)

Since you can't target the `<br>` element with css, you have to use javascript. Here's how you can accomplish what you want with jQuery:

`// Add two spaces before and after any <br /> tag

$('br').replaceWith('&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;');`

Play with the number of `&nbsp;` elements to acheive your padding on both ends.

Here's an updated Fiddle demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/4Gs2E/8/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `float: left` instead of `display: inline`:

http://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/4Gs2E/1/

Comment: yea floating left sets the element to inline block anyway
in this example where the text is longer:
http://jsfiddle.net/xXhbL/1/
the background needs to wrap around the text only and not the block

Comment: I see now. I'm afraid it's not possible then, without adding extra elements. But that shouldn't be that hard. Actually, the only thing you need is to replace `<br>` with `</h1><h1>`. The styling can be done in a separate style sheet, which would be a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Usually that is implemented by wrapping each word in an own `SPAN` which has border.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to make css-animated menu for myself. Workaround I have found is to wrap your INLINE-BLOCK element (change in css if necessary, lets call it a *span* with such an attribute for purpose of this solution) into *block* element. Then I'm using margins of *span* as it was padding for the surrounding *div*.

```
div.menuopt {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 500px;
    height: 150px;
    background: grey;
}
span.menuopt {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ApbQS/

hope it will help anyone